# Why specify "document" or "body" BEFORE binding a jQuery event listener?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, event-delegation

In jQuery, there are numerous ways to bind actions to events, and to add listeners for them. With this I have no problem.

But what I can't understand, is what would be the purpose of specifying "body" or "document" for that matter, before listening for an event?

Consider the following code :

```js
$(".example-button").click(function() {
  $(this).text("I have been clicked");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="example-button" role="button" type="button">I have not been clicked yet.</button>
<button class="example-button" role="button" type="button">I have not been clicked yet.</button>
```

This will bind the event "click" to the buttons with class "example-button", and when they are clicked it will change the appropriate buttons text to let you know as such.

However, I often see programmers (and often quite experienced programmers) write the following code :

```js
$("body").on("click", ".example-button", function() {
  $(this).text("I have been clicked");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="example-button" role="button" type="button">I have not been clicked yet.</button>
<button class="example-button" role="button" type="button">I have not been clicked yet.</button>
```

Which achieves the same perceived effect as the first code block.

My question is, **Why?**

More specifically, why bind it to the document or body, and then check for the clicks on that? Isn't that an additional section of redundant code?

Thinking to justify it, I came up with the theory that perhaps by specifying the click is bound to the body would ensure the body has been loaded - but this is not correct as $("body").on("click") etc does not equal $(document).ready().

Can anyone provide additional insight into this? I can't seem to find my answer in the jQuery documentation, as it pre-defaults to assuming I'm looking for the aforementioned

```
$(document).ready().
```

Comment: Because the latter is a delegated handler. The former will only work on `.example-button` elements which exist in the DOM when the event handler is created. The latter will work on `.example-button` elements which are added to the DOM at *any* point in the page life cycle (including those added through AJAX requests etc). If you want more information, read the docs for `on()`: http://api.jquery.com/on/#on-events-selector-data-handler, specifically the 'Direct and delegated event handlers' part.

Comment: http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan That's extremely helpful, and immediate. Thanks for the response. While it's not quite within the scope of the question, what would ever be the purpose of using the former (intentionally) as opposed to the latter? Wouldn't that just open up more potential for errors to occur? A big thank you to the direction towards the documentation also.

Comment: @Taplar Thanks a lot Taplar for the link to that specific part of the documentation, I'll read up on this immediately.

Comment: Non-delegate event bindings are fine for static content that you know will be there, and is not dynamic.  Given that, there isn't a big reason to use delegate event bindings for those.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

Comment: `what would ever be the purpose of using the former (intentionally) as opposed to the latter?` If you know that the DOM is never going to change (or at least the element you're targetting is never going to change) then you can use a static handler. Delegated handlers are only used when needed as they require the event to bubble up the DOM to be caught on the primary selector (`body` in your example above). This can be problematic when things such as `stopPropagation()` are used in the intermediate elements.

Comment: @Taplar Perhaps there was a misunderstanding. I meant my additional question in the comment may not be within the scope of the question I originally asked, as it could be perceived as a separate question. Thank you for your additional explanation.

Comment: Note, you can still use delegate event listeners for static content, if you are of a mind that you want to limit the number of event handlers in the DOM, but that would be entirely a coding preference on the developers part.

Comment: A massive thank you to you both, for your in-depth explanations. This is really helping to improve my understanding of jQuery, JavaScript, and the DOM as a whole. I'm unsure whether to accept my answer marked as a duplicate or not, because the linked "potential duplicate" is about a slightly different subject. I'm considering editing my question (with this new information), to then ask, "Why would you ever NEED the former over the latter, for anything other than preference?" I believe this question may serve other users of the sight.

Comment: There is no need.  Just preference.

Comment: I agree the possible duplicate doesn't *ask* the same question, but does give you insight into the reasons, thus giving you the same answer and by reciprocation it is the same subject, but perhaps dwells less on the **reasons** as provided by the answer here.  (I've removed my close vote) (I wasn't initially sure whether to make it a possible dup or just "related").

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why use a delegate event listener?

## 1) Content doesn't exist yet

```js
//#container is empty, but we will create children in the future
//we can use a delagate now that will handle the events from the children
//created later
$('#container').on('click', '.action', function (e) {
  console.log(e.target.innerText);
});

//lets create a new action that didn't exist before the binding
$('#container').append('<button class="action">Hey!  You Caught Me!</button>');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

## 2) Content exists, but changes

```js
//#container has an existing child, but it only matches one of our
//delegate event bindings.  Lets see what happens when we change it
//so that it matches each in turn

$('#container').on('click', '.action:not(.active)', function (e) {
  console.log('Awww, your not active');
  $(e.target).addClass('active');
});

$('#container').on('click', '.action.active', function (e) {
  console.log('Hell yeah!  Active!');
  $(e.target).removeClass('active');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <button class="action">Hey! You Caught Me!</button>
</div>
```

> Why use a non-delegate event listener over a delegate event listener?

## 1) Content is static and pre-existing

Either because you know the content is static and will not change, and you do not have a need for one.  Otherwise, you may have a preference to use delegates, which is fine as a developer preference.

## 2) You can prevent events from bubbling

However, using non-delegate event listeners can also be used in conjunction with delegates to prevent operations.  Consider the following:

```js
//#container has three children.  Lets say we have a delegate listener for
//the buttons, but we only want it to work for two of them.  How could we
//use a non-delegate to make this work?

//delegate that targets all the buttons in the container
$('#container').on('click', 'button', function (e) {
  console.log('Yeah!');
});

$('.doNotDoSomething').on('click', function (e) {
  console.log('Do not do the delegate logic');
  
  //by stopping the propagation of the click event, it will not bubble up
  //the DOM for the delegate event handler to process it.  In this way, we
  //can prevent a delegate event handler from working for a nested child.
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <button class="doSomething">Do It!</button>
  <button class="doNotDoSomething">Nooooo!</button>
  <button class="doSomethingElse">Do This Instead!</button>
</div>
```

## 3) You want your bindings to be removable

Another reason to potentially want to use non-delegate event listeners is be cause they **are** attached to the elements themselves.  So, given that, if you delete the element, the binding also goes away with it.  While this may be an issue with dynamic content where you want the binding to always be there for the elements, there may be cases where you want that to happen.